# Is this the right way to use generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

```
class Matrix<T>{
   private List<Attribute<T>> attributes;

   public Matrix(T type){
      attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute<T>>();
      attributes.add(new Attribute<T>(type));
   }
}
```

I feel like in the constructor, these two lines should be use a specific type, not the generic T:

```
attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute<T>>();
      attributes.add(new Attribute<T>(type));
```

But the compiler doesn't complain. So this is the right way to define this class?

Comment: Is `Attribute` a builtin or user defined class?

Comment: Does the generic type parameter of `Attribute` need to match the generic type parameter of `Matrix`? If so, it's correct.

Comment: Yes, Attribute is a user defined enum type.

Comment: @Adrian, yes, they have to match.

Comment: It's hard for us to say for sure without knowing more about what you're trying to do with the `Matrix` class and its `attributes`. We can certainly say that working with a type variable such as `T` is hardly unusual. It could even be reasonable to say that being able to work with type variables instead of concrete types is the entire point of generics.

Comment: Why do you think the constructor should use a specific type? Then you've lost your ability to deal with arbitrary classes, which is the motivation for generics!

Comment: _"I feel like in the constructor, these two lines should be use a specific type, not the generic T"_ Why do you feel this way? Why do you expect the compiler to complain about it?

Comment: :) because i am a kind of newbie and feel good when I doesn't complain, though a little nervous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thats the right way. The only thing where you might be wrong is that your Parameter in the constructor should not be namend type, but value. The Type is T.

If you need to, you can say that your Generic has to a childtype of something else. Let's say we have a class which holds an Exception. We could just make a Membervariable of Type Exception. But when getting the Exception from inside this Object, we don't want to cast our Exception to a more specific one.

So we use a Generic which must be a childtype of Exception:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends Exception>
{
    private final T value;

    public SomeClass(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now we can do stuff like this:

```
SomeClass<ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException> obj = new SomeClass<>(new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException());
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc = obj.getValue(); // no cast from Exception to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException needed
```

Comment: I don't understand this part, "should not be namend type, but value". Could you be more specific?

Comment: it could be named type but it would be more accurate to name it value as T is the type.

Comment: So it's a naming issue. Thanks.

Comment: Great example to illustrate the example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like in the constructor, these two lines should be use a specific type, not the generic T

No, because your class `Matrix` is generic on the type parameter `T`. This means that it encapsulates a list of attributes of the type `T`, namely: `List<Attribute<T>>`.

If you use it with `Integer`:

```
Matrix<Integer> integerMatrix = new Matrix<>(1);
```

Then `1` would be inside the first attribute of the list.

However, if you declare another matrix with `String`:

```
Matrix<String> stringMatrix = new Matrix<>("hello");
```

Then your matrix will hold attributes that encapsulate `String` values.

Comment: When don't you write "new Matrix<Integer>(1)", but "new Matrix<>(1)"?

Comment: @user697911 I'm using the diamond operator. It's enough if you specify the generic type at the left hand side of the `=`